# Разница между типами bool и int признаках для обучения модели

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, модель

Есть ли разница в предоставлении модели качественного признака (допустим бинарного мужчина/женщина) в виде true false или в виде 1 0, при учете, что есть еще другие количественные признаки отмасштабированные в диапазон от 0 до 1? (то есть в итоге на вход модели либо подаются все численные признаки, либо один bool + численные)

Comment: Скорее всего они будут проинтерпретированы по-питоновски как `0` и `1`, то есть разницы не будет. А в чём сложность просто взять и проверить? )  В общем случае это зависит от того, как с данными обращается конкретная модель. Какие-то из моделей могут счесть булевы признаки не числовыми, а категориальными, с которыми модель работает несколько по-другому.

Comment: Вам удалось в итоге разобраться - есть в вашем случае какая-то разница или нет?

Answer (score 1):

В python bool и int, не имеют по сути разницы. bool приводится к int без проблем, и может использоваться напрямую как int:

```py
print(3 + True)   # 4
print(5 - True)   # 4
print(False + 6)  # 6
print(True * 14)  # 14

a = {True: 6}
print( a[1]) # Выведет 6

b = {False: 6}
print(b[0]) # Выведет 6
```

Поэтому с точки зрения математики для python нет никакой разницы.

В C++ же, например, разница может быть. Там по сути `bool` это алиас для числового типа, напрмер `int`. Однако в C++ разница могла бы быть, потому что некоторые элементы например станадртной библиотеки оптимизированы для использования `bool`, хоть `bool` и хранит 0/1, что по сути занимает `1 бит`, современные компьютеры индексируют память по байтово, поэтому минимальный размер `bool` даже в C/C++ будет занимать как минимум 8 бит. Но например динамический массив из 1000 bool будет занимать всего 125 байт, благодаря встроенным оптимизациям:

```
std::vector<bool> bool_vec(1000); // Размер ~ 125 байт (оптимизации для std::vector<bool>)
std::vector<int> int_vec(1000);  // Размер ~ 4000 байт (32-битный int)
```

Но это, скорее всего, может быть полезно только для общего развития

Comment: Вопрос заключался скорее в интерпритацией моделью признака числового типа как булевого, если его значения состоят из 0 и 1, тк на вход этой же модели подаются и другие численные значения в диапазоне от 0 до 1